# Play music depending on the rotation in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

Is it possible to play the french music only between angle of the "world" 0 deg to 27 deg? I have made the rotation of the world depending on scrolling. Thanks guys :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var angle,
scroll = 0;
var $world = $('#world');
var $body = $('body');
```

// french music
    var $french = $('#french');

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

angle = $body.scrollTop() / 28;
$world.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate('+angle+'deg)').css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate('+angle+'deg)').css('-o-transform', 'rotate('+angle+'deg)').css('-ms-transform', 'rotate('+angle+'deg)');


$(french)[0].play(); 

console.log(scroll);
});
});
```

**update**

is this correct? it still doesn't let me play any other music except for the first one (french)

```
            if(angle >=0 && angle <=26) {
        $(french)[0].play();
    }
    if(angle >27 && angle <=74) {
        $(british)[1].play();
    }
    if(angle >75 && angle <=115) {
        $(ny)[2].play();
    }
    if(angle >116 && angle <=164) {
        $(la)[3].play();
    }
    if(angle >165 && angle <=210) {
        $(japanese)[4].play();
    }
    if(angle >211 && angle <=270) {
        $(chinese)[5].play();
    }
    if(angle >271 && angle <=310) {
        $(indian)[6].play();
    }
    if(angle >311 && angle <=333) {
        $(egyptian)[7].play();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

angle = $body.scrollTop() / 28;
$world.css({'-moz-transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
           '-webkit-transform':'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
           '-o-transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
           '-ms-transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)'});

if(angle >=0 || angle <=27)
{$(french)[0].play(); 
}
console.log(scroll);
```

**update**

```
if(angle >=28 || angle <=72)
{$(french)[1].play();
// another music play 
}
```

Comment: thank you and if I would like to stop the music when it reaches 27 degree and play another music between 28 deg and 74 deg?